# Is lazy loading possible in dapper? And what is the difference between the generic (POCO) and dynamic API?

Tags: c#, dapper

I have two question about working with dapper:

1. Is there any way to load navigation key property like entity-framework (lazy-loading)?
2. What's difference between `POCO serialization` and `dynamic serialization`?
   which is better? and how can I use this serialization?

Comment: Please ask one question per question.

Comment: Sorry man. wont happen again :D

Comment: Also, "Working with dapper" is not a very good title since this is not a tutorial site.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter any suggestion for title?

Comment: @IliaG it isn't a *question* would be the main issue with the title

Comment: @Raika I've proposed a different title - any good?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> is there any way to load navigation key property like entity-framework (lazy-loading)?

No, Dapper is a direct-SQL library, and that's why it's so ridiculously fast. There is no overhead surrounding automated loading. You can however load more than one entity at once.

> what's difference between POCO serialization and dynamic serialization? which is better? and how can i use this serialization?

POCO serialization is more efficient because the type is well known at compile time, dynamic serialization is a bit more expensive because it has to be evaluated at run-time. Other than that there isn't really a difference.

However, I would recommend Dapper above ***all other*** libraries anywhere. It's simple, fast, and extremely flexible. And believe me, I've used a lot of frameworks and libraries for data access.

[Dapper Documentation](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)

Have a look at **Multi Mapping** and **Multiple Results**

Comment: strictly speaking, the *serialization* doesn't really notice any run-time evaluation, since it doesn't use the `dynamic` API to assign the values. The *caller* will, though.

Comment: Thank you @MarcGravell for the clarification. So really the act of accessing the object will experience the performance hit (albeit about as relevant as the fact that there is white and brown rice)?

Comment: indeed; but even then, I wouldn't say the performance is the main factor in the decision. The formality of the API (and whether the data is consumed locally or at a different layer) is the bigger issue for me.

Comment: @MarcGravell, fully understood, and also why I just had to +1 your answer, that clarification was certainly a new perspective on the differences between when you should use typed classes vs. dynamic, regardless of their correlation to Dapper, just overall.

Comment: thanks for that. one question irrelevant to this question. its better to pass Object to my business layer from UI or pass parameters? `Thing.Add(thing)` or `Thing.Add(title,number)`. which is better?

Comment: @Raika, I think that's more a matter of preference and very subjective to the solution as a whole. A lot of people have gotten in the habit of passing objects because it's easy, I have started getting away from objects because it loosely couples everything, but I don't do it every time.

Comment: @Raika if "thing" is actually "SomeType thing", then that is generally fine: but not "object thing"

Answer (score 8):

1: nope; none at all, unless you roll it entirely yourself. It is intentionally minimalistic and deterministic

2: materializing into a POCO is handy if you want to expose that data to other parts of your application, for example as data for a view-model; `Query<Customer>`, for example, can populate well-known `Customer` objects that you can code against in other places. `dynamic` is very *convenient*, but is not very *explorable* - and won't work well for data-binding or intellisense. It is, however, really handy for DAL methods that remain very local, or example

```
var row = conn.Query("select qty, cost from parts where id = @id",
    new { id }).Single();
int qty = row.qty;
decimal cost = row.cost;
// and off we go...
```

or:

```
var lookup = conn.Query("select id, name from somelookup").ToDictionary(
      x => (int)x.id, x => (string)x.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no lazy loading support in dapper unless you hand craft something using the `Lazy<T>` class in .NET.

POCO Serialization is where you define a class and instances of this are used to add/edit/read rows from a table.

Dynamic Serialization is where you use `dynamic` objects in .NET (where you don't define classes).

Dynamic will be quicker to get going, although you will have no intelisense or type safety. POCOs will take a bit longer to get set up (as you need to create each class you want to use) but you keep type safety and intelisense.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide another option for lazy loading using Dapper is Castle's Dynamic Proxy. I have successfully managed to write a POC framework using Dapper, Dynamic Proxy and Mediatr to enable lazy loading on properties at access time, i.e.

e.g.

```
public class Customer
{
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public IEnumerable<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine
{
    /*
     * ...
     */
}
```

Then when you use like this:

```
Customer customer = ... /*Load from database*/
/* Perform some logic */
// Access "Orders"

foreach(Order order in customer.Orders)//loads orders from the database
{
    foreach(OrderLine in order.OrderLines) //loads order lines from the database
    {
    }
}
```

So you don't have to just use `Lazy<T>` it can be done in other ways

Comment: Can you demo some details.?

Comment: As for your example it looks like every time you need to get the orders of your customer you have to call a method first to query those order for a specific customer. Then you set those orders for your customer model. Can you provide an example of use of your logic? How do you call this query method? It seems to be quite far from EF lazy load.